# rails no route matches only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration

I have a rails app that works fine in dev env but raises error in production after pushing to heroku (db migrated as well).

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    resources :notifications, only: [:create, :index] do
      collection do
        get :other_notifications, :chat_notifications
      end
    end
    resource :profile
    ....
    ....
```

heroku log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
2015-12-04T05:54:08.351276+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <% else %>
2015-12-04T05:54:08.351277+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <div class="notification-line-checked">
2015-12-04T05:54:08.351278+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: <% end %>
2015-12-04T05:54:08.351279+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= link_to user_path(notification.sender) do %>
2015-12-04T05:54:08.351280+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     <% if notification.notification_type == "chat" %>
2015-12-04T05:54:08.351282+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:       <p class="subject"><%= notification.sender.profile.first_name %> <%= notification.sender.profile.last_name %> has sent you a message on chat.</p>
2015-12-04T05:54:08.351283+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     <% else %>
```

rendering:

```
  <div class = "other-notifications-index">
    <%= render @other_notifications %>
  </div>
```

Again, it works fine in dev. Can be caused by older schema versions where sender.id was not defined? So rails tries to get those old records maybe and just can't find the sender.id for those? Prior to the current version I only used recipient.id and sender name was used thru some methods.

Comment: can you please post your users controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
<%= link_to user_path(notification.sender) do %>
```

You'd better check if `notification.sender` is `nil` before create the link. Otherwise, you will get `:id=>nil` and cannot match your route.

Comment: Yang, what is the most efficient way to do this? Based on your suggestion I put <% unless notification.sender.blank? %> in the _notification.html.erb and it's working, but I'm not sure if it is the best solution.